# filling a textarea with html and show &lt; and not <

Tags: asp.net, html

I have built a little editor for resource files.

So I show the content of a resource item in a textarea.

```
<textarea cols="85" rows="12" id='EditItemTextArea'><%# Eval("Translation")%></textarea>
```

However, that content is shown as html symbols, so when I load `&lt;` in the textarea and i look at the source, I see `&lt;`
like this:

```
<textarea cols="85" rows="12" id='EditItemTextArea'>consumption.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;</textarea>
```

But in the textarea (in the browser) a `<` is shown, and when I save the content of the textarea, I read `<` and not `&lt;`

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Whats the difference between < and < ?

Comment: not sure what u mean ... the SO editor isn't doing u much justice .. u might wanna use code mode so its clear what u are trying to tell us ..

Comment: Sorry for the < and < problem, thanks for @dan for editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) (and [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to get a decoded HTML back)? Your code could look like the following:

```
<textarea cols="85" rows="12" id='EditItemTextArea' name='EditItemTextArea'><%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Translation").ToString())%></textarea>
```

Code-behind:

```
string html = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(base.Request["EditItemTextArea"]);
```

Comment: I thought, when i've read your answer: no, no HtmlEncode, my html is already in the right format, it just shows wrong. Tried it anyway and it does this: it replaces `&gt;` to `&amp;gt;`, and that works! So glad i tried, and thanks for the answer.

Comment: and because `&amp;gt;` shows as `&gt;` in the textarea (which is the content i want to store in the db) i don't have to decode it on the server, because `&;gt;` is in the form post, and that's what i need.

Answer (score 1):

The HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and HttpUtility.HtmlDecode methods should be of use here.

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, this you might also try this:

```
<textarea cols="85" rows="12" id='EditItemTextArea'><%# HttpUtility.Decode(Eval("Translation").ToString())%></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

[populating a textarea with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037263/populating-a-textarea-with-special-characters)

[Displaying HTML and other code in a Textarea in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523093/displaying-html-and-other-code-in-a-textarea-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at System.Web.HttpUtility class. Guess HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode methods helps you.